# How to determine duration of a common stock whose dividends grow in perpetuity?

Tags: stocks, calculation, dividends, duration

What is the duration of a common stock whose dividends are expected to grow at a constant rate in perpetuity? Specifically, how can I compute this, since the dividends will grow forever?

---

**Update**: Ok, to make this more realistic, assume that the discount rate r is higher than the growth rate g, and both r and g are positive.

For reference, the formula for the duration is = summation of t x PV(period t) / (Total PV)

The only thing I don't get is to sum up the t x PV(period t). I have a feeling it would sum to infinity though.

Answer (score 2):

The Dividend Discount Model is based on the concept that the present value of a stock is the sum of all future dividends, discounted back to the present. Since you said:

> dividends are expected to grow at a constant rate in perpetuity

... the Gordon Growth Model is a simple variant of the DDM, tailored for a firm in "steady state" mode, with dividends growing at a rate that can be sustained forever.

```
Present Stock Value = DPS / (r - g)
```

Consider McCormick (MKC), who's last dividend was 31 cents, or $1.24 annualized. The dividend has been growing just a little over 7% annually. Let's use a discount, or hurdle rate of 10%.

```
1.24 / (.10 - .073) = $45.93
```

MKC closed today at $50.32, for what it's worth.

The model is extremely sensitive to inputs. As g approaches r, the stock price rises to infinity. If g > r, stock goes negative. Be conservative with 'g' -- it must be sustainable *forever*.

The next step up in complexity is the two-stage DDM, where the company is expected to grow at a higher, *unsustainable rate* in the early years (stage 1), and then settling down to the terminal rate for stage 2. Stage 1 is the present value of dividends during the high growth period. Stage 2 is the Gordon Model, starting at the end of stage 1, and discounting back to the present.

Consider Abbott Labs (ABT). The current annual dividend is $1.92, the current dividend growth rate is 12%, and let's say that continues for ten years (n), after which point the growth rate is 5% in perpetuity. Again, the discount rate is 10%.
Stage 1 is calculated as follows:

```
( DPS  * (1+g) * [1 - ( (1+g)^n / (1+r)^n )] ) / (r - g)
( 1.92 * 1.12  * [1 - ( 3.1058  /  2.5937 )] ) / (.10 - .12)
( 1.92 * 1.12  * -0.1974                     ) / -0.02       = 21.22
```

Stage 2 is GGM, using not today's dividend, but the 11th year's dividend, since stage 1 covered the first ten years. 'gn' is the terminal growth, 5% in our case.

```
DPS_11 = DPS * ((1+g)^(n+1)) = 6.68
```

then...

```
DPS_11 / ( (r - gn)   * (1 + r)  ^(n+1) )
6.68   / ( .10 - .05) * (1 + .10)^11    ) = 51.50
```

The value of the stock today is 21.22 + 51.50 = 72.72

ABT closed today at $56.72, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that dividends grow in perpetuity does not prevent one from calculating duration.  In fact, many academic papers look at exactly this problem, such as [Lewin and Satchell](http://www.econ.cam.ac.uk/dae/repec/cam/pdf/WP0104.pdf).  This [Wilmott thread](http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=9450) discusses some of the pros and cons of the concept in some detail.

PS: Although I was already broadly familiar with the literature and I use the duration of equities in some of my every-day work as a professional working in finance, I found the links above doing a simple google search for "equity duration."

Comment: I appreciate the kindness. My answer which stated the word "duration" is not associated with stocks has been removed. Apparently, it is used by some, I'd just never seen this before. I stand corrected, and am smarter than before I met you, sheegaon.

Comment: Could you double-check the Wilmott thread URL? I can't access it. My browser just times out. Thanks!

Comment: @FeralOink URL still works for me, try again.  Maybe you need to be logged in to Wilmott to view?

Comment: I just tried the Wilmott link, worked fine for me now. And it is a good discussion of pro's (and definitely of con's!) of using equity duration. Even refers to the Lewin and Satchell paper you posted. Thank you!