# What is the difference between fixed-income duration and equity duration?

Tags: stocks, fixed-income, metric, duration

I noticed this question, [How to determine duration of a common stock whose dividends grow in perpetuity?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/how-to-determine-duration-of-a-common-stock-whose-dividends-grow-in-perpetuity) I am familiar with the concept of duration for bonds, but not for common stock (actually, it is unfamiliar to me for equity-type securities of any sort... other than convertible bonds... maybe).

What are the differences in definition and usage of duration for securities that ARE fixed-income versus those that ARE NOT fixed-income?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bond has a duration that can be easily calculated. It's the time weighted average of all the payments you'll receive and helpful to understand the effect a change in rates will have on that instrument.

The duration of a stock, on the other hand, is a forced construct to then use in other equations to help calculate, say, the summation of a dividend stream. I can calculate the duration of a bond and come up with an answer that's not up for discussion or dispute. The duration of a stock, on the other hand, isn't such a number. Will J&J last 50 more years? Will Apple? Who knows?